# Looping through XML records using xElement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following XML

```
     <xml>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <products>
              <product>
                    <name>Product 1</ProductName>
                    <id>1</ProductId>
              </product>
              <product>
                    <name>Product 2</ProductName>
                    <id>2</ProductId>
              </product>
              <product>
                    <name>Product 3</ProductName>
                    <id>3</ProductId>
              </product>
          </products>
      </xml>
```

And i have the following code for looping through the products

```
   Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load("aaa.xml")
   Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()
       For Each product In products
           Console.WriteLine(product.Elements("name").Value)
       Next product
```

but `product.Elements("name").Value` is giving error. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: why you have so long element names in xml? `product>ProductName` you can change to `product>Name`

Comment: ok i have edited my question. Lets assume the xml has now short name. What next :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the XML element names (although your edit has invalid XML - you only changed the opening tag, not the closing tag).

The issue is that products contains the child elements of the XML document you loaded - in this case, `<Version>` and `<Products>....</Products>` (i.e., the all the products tags and their children).

What you want to do is grab a collection of all the `<name>` nodes, and you can do this one of two ways:

```
Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Element("products").Element("product").Element("name")
```

or

```
Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("name")
```

Then, in your `For Each`, simply call `Value` on `Product`, like this:

```
For Each product As XElement In products
    Console.WriteLine(product.Value)
Next
```

The output will be

```
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
```

**EDITED to add complete code**

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim Xml As String = "<xml><version>1.0</version><products><product><name>Product 1</name><id>1</id></product><product><name>Product 2</name><id>2</id></product><product><name>Product 3</name><id>3</id></product></products></xml>"

        Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Parse(Xml)

        Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("name")

        For Each product As XElement In products
            Console.WriteLine(product.Value)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: i got the following exception after trying the code you have suggested `Unable to cast object of type` `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` `to type` `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]`

Comment: @KhawerZeshan - I've tested the code and it works. The only difference is that I'm using a string to load the initial XElement.  I'll post the complete code in my answer for reference - double-check your For Each loop, as it sounds like the error is there.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Name contains the child elements of the XML document you loaded - in this case, `<Version>` and `<name>....</name>` (i.e., the all the name tags and their children).

What you want to do is grab a collection of all the `<Name>` nodes and `<tel>` nodes, and you can do on this way:

```
 Dim Names As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("Name")

  For Each Name As XElement In Names 
        MsgBox((Name.Value)
  Next
```

Same you can do for "Tel"

**Complete code:**

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim cbFileName As String = "<xml><version>1.0</version><name>A1</name><tel>12</tel><name>A2</name><tel>21</tel><name>A3</name><tel>11</tel></xml>"

    Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(cbFileName.Text)

    Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("name")

    For Each product As XElement In products
        MessageBox.Show(product.Value)
    Next

    Dim Telephone As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("tel")

    For Each telep As XElement In Telephone
        MessageBox.Show(telep.Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

**Output:**

A1
A2
A3

12
21
11

Answer (score 0):

`product.Elements("name")` return `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so it has no `.Value` property. Try this one:

```
Dim products As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()
For Each product In products
    Console.WriteLine(product.Element("name").Value)
Next product
```

Comment: Based on OP's posted XML, this fails as well, because the first `product` is `<version>1.0</version>`, which doesn't contain a "name" element.  A NullReferenceException occurs.  That's why I used `xelement.Descedants("name")` in my answer.